# Read a file and map to a Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, list, hashmap, tokenize

So, I've got a file which is written in the following way:

X - Y

A - B

X - Z

A - C

X - L

A - N

Basically, there's a relationship between the two entities.

I wanted to map this onto a map, so that one unique key could be mapped onto a list of values.

What I want is something like this:
{X = [Y,Z,L]},{A = [B,C,N]}, etc...

---

I figured the best way to store them would be in a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

I had the following algorithm in mind:

- Read the incoming file using `Files.readAllLines()` to store the lines as a `List<String>`.
- Tokenize the lines using `String.split()` or `StringTokenizer` into a `List<List<String>>`

What do I do after this? I just need an algorithm, and mind you, **This is not a home assignment**. I'm writing a simple Java application for myself that tokenizes files like these and exports them to a CSV.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well try your own algorithm , see if it works and if you have issues come back and we'll help.

Comment: You are almost there, take the first element in the line use it as a key to your map and add the rest of the split[1...N] to your Map with this key as values

Answer (score 5):

My first idea was to do it like this:

```
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("X - Y", "A - B", "X - Z", "A - C", "X - L", "A - N"));
    Map<String, List<String>> pairs = new HashMap<>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] pair = line.split("-");
        String key = pair[0].trim();
        String val = pair[1].trim();
        List<String> valueFromMap = pairs.get(key);
        if(valueFromMap == null) {
            valueFromMap = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        valueFromMap.add(val);
        pairs.put(key, valueFromMap);
    }
    System.out.println(pairs.toString());
```

Comment: FYI, if you want the values for each key to be unique, you could use  Map<String, Set<String>>

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put `pairs.put(key, valueFromMap);` directly after `valueFromMap = new ArrayList<>();`?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class prova {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String,ArrayList<String>> mappa= new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();

        File dir = new File(".");
        File fin = new File(dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "file.txt");

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);

        //Construct BufferedReader from InputStreamReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" - ");
            String key = splitted[0];
            String value = splitted[1];
            ArrayList<String> v;

                 v = mappa.get(key);

            if (v==null)
                v = new ArrayList<String>();

            v.add(value);
            mappa.put(key, v);
        }
        System.out.println(mappa.toString());
        br.close();
    }

}
```

My output is: {A=[B, C, N], X=[Y, Z, L]}

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<String,List<String>> graphlist = new TreeMap<>();


    String path = "/Users/addodennis/Desktop/Projects/HotelReservation/src/Data/Dlist";
    String str;
    try(BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));) {
        while ((str = read.readLine()) != null){

            String[] list = str.split(" - ");
            String k = list[0].trim();
            String v1 = list[1].trim();
            List<String> ad = graphlist.get(k);
            if (ad == null){
                ad = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            ad.add(v1);
            graphlist.put(k,ad);


        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





}
```

for A will give

> {A=[B, C, N]}

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it in Java 8:

```
System.out.println(
    Files.readAllLines(file).stream()
        .map(line -> line.split("-"))
        .collect(
            groupingBy(
                array -> array[0].trim(), 
                mapping(array -> array[1].trim(), 
                toList())
            )
        )
);
```

**Output:**

```
{A=[B, C, N], X=[Y, Z, L]}
```